# Ruby - парсинг страницы

Tags: json, ubuntu, парсер, ruby

Доброго времени суток.

Стоит задача получить HTML-код со внешнего сайта,а именно вот эти 2 значения (13265.51 и 0:13) - меняются постоянно, но это же не играет роли

[image: какие данные надо получить]

пока что пытаюсь получить хотяб первое число

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'json'

url = 'https://olymptrade.com/'
html = open(url)

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
rate = []
doc.css('.cutoffG').each do |cutoffG|
  description = cutoffG.at_css('.pin_text')

  rate << description
end

puts rate.to_s
```

но что-то не особо получается.
Значения которые нужно получить оба находятся внутри класса cutoffG, и каждое значение внутри класса pin_text, все классы в коде прописываю

но в ответ возвращается пустой массив[image: ответ сервера]

---

Насчёт подключения к странице

Скриншот данных которые мне нужны я делала на странице https://olymptrade.com/en-us/platform, но программа к ней подключаться не хочет, выдает [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**НО!** Если в авторизованном состоянии зайти на https://olymptrade.com/, сразу переадресация идёт на вышеуказанную страницу (с которой и нужно получить данные)

Я не до конца понимаю как это работает, использует ли программа мои куки, мой логин и пароль, или говорит с сервером как будто впервые встретились.
Ну и самый главный вопрос остаются на повестке этой ночи - что мне сделать чтоб произошло чудо и всё заработало?

Заранее спасибо за ответ или просто за то что дочитали до конца

Answer (score 2):

Я бы наверное тут использовал сокеты. Данные слишком часто обновляются, а это слишком частые запросы к серверу и он может заблокировать клиента.

```
gem install faye-websocket
```

Пример

```
require 'faye/websocket'
require 'eventmachine'

EM.run {
  ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new('wss://olymptrade.com/ws2')

  ws.on :open do |event|
    p [:open]
    ws.send('{"uuid":"JCBQ7XBRMYSL0JB4N5","pair":"EURUSD","size":60}')
  end

  ws.on :message do |event|
    p [:message, event.data]
  end

  ws.on :close do |event|
    p [:close, event.code, event.reason]
    ws = nil
  end
}
```

Данные

```
 '{"uuid":"JCBQ7XBRMYSL0JB4N5","pair":"EURUSD","size":60}'
```

Их я взял их вот отсюда - http://joxi.ru/DrlQ6ppCvgWk8m

Можете сравнить получаемы данные с данными на сайте, они одинаковые.

Если хотите именно парсить, то Вам нужно пройти аутентификацию в любом случае и подставить куки или можно использовать chrome headless.

Вот тут есть примеры - https://readysteadycode.com/howto-scrape-websites-with-ruby-and-headless-chrome

Comment: Действительно работает. Спасибо.
А при использовании websocket он всегда будет в терминал выводиться, или можно его значение занести в массив, например, раз в минуту?

Comment: В блоке ws.on :message можно производить любые манипуляции. В данном примере вывод в терминал сделан для демонстрации. Вообще потом вывод нужно убрать и сделать уже требуемую логику. Можете добавлять значения из сокета в redis и уже из своего приложения подтягивать данные раз в минуту (ну как вариант). Тут уже зависит от требований к приложению.